# Finding Percentage Difference between the Id value passed in the filter and others row values in the column using spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

i have column Id and the corresponding value as example in the below values.

Id    Value
A      0.0045
B      0.0044
C      0.0043
D      0.0052

I have a Id based filter  where if one value is passed (eg: A it has to find difference percentage with all other id's like

Id Compared_id  percentage_difference
A    B           (0.0044/0.0045)*100==>97.7777777777(every time small number be in numerator)
A    C           (0.0043/0.0045)*100==>95.5555555555
A    D           (0.0045/0.0052)*100==>86.5384615384

Same should be shown while selecting B or c or nth id.

I have achieved for pre calculated value by storing the values in excel by using the below code.

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv(r"filename.csv")

list =[]
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    print("processing {} record".format(index))
    if str(row['IDValue']) != 'nan':
        for i,row1 in df.iterrows():
            rate = 0
            if str(row1['IDValue']) != 'nan' and (row1['IDValue'] != row['IDValue']):
#               print("index: {}".format(i))
                if row['IDvalue'] < row1['IDValue']:
                    rate = (row['IDValue'] / row1['IDValue'])*100
                else:
                    rate = (row1['IDValue'] / row['IDValue'])*100

                if rate <= 100 and rate >= 80.00:

                   list.append([row['ID'],row1['ID'],rate])
```

how to achieve the same output by passing the input a the filter id value and creating as a new calculated column in spotfire.